# PHP form validation issue

Tags: php, forms, validation

Using this script to validate forms: http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/php_validation/

Rules look like that

```
 $rules[] = "required,user_name,This field is required.";
 $rules[] = "letters_only,user_name,This field is required.";
 $rules[] = "length>5,user_name,Please enter a value that is over 5 characters long.";
```

First rule checks if user filled or not the form field named user_name. The problem is, it check all other rules for user_name form field and echoes error messages even if user doesn't fill  the user_name. I mean how to fix the code to decline all other rules related to exact field if required field returned false?

You can download the php code from here. http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/php_validation/php_validation.zip

Comment: Post code where you're applying the rules.

Comment: in signup form. lets say this one http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/php_validation/ open "Demo form and explanation" from right panel

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to handle your flow-control better. That is, return false, exit, etc. when you hit a failure condition. Stop processing, return an error message and allow the user to try again.

Comment: that;s not the answer, if you wanna help, lets find his problem and fix it together. Here is the chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4892/php-validation